# Setting different text of a textview from an arraylist

Tags: java, android

I have a `textview` created programmatically in a loop. On a click of a button i want to fill each `textview` created with different values from the array how do i achieve this. Here is what happens when the button is clicked. Thanks for the help.

```
    btnPnar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            listLayout.removeAllViews();

            for (EditText et : editTextCollection)
            {
                gottenText = et.getText().toString();
                inputList.add(gottenText);
                Collections.shuffle(inputList);
            }
            // Creating alert Dialog with one Button
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.DialogeTheme);


            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("PNAR");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Amount of Numbers to Pick");
            final EditText input; input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            input.setLayoutParams(lp);
            input.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f06292"));
            input.setInputType(2);
            alertDialog.setView(input);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("DONE",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    pnarGotten = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
                    Collections.shuffle(inputList);


                    for (int n =0; n<pnarGotten; n++) {

                        TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                        textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        textView.setText(inputList.get(0));
                        textView.setText(inputList.get(1));
                        listLayout.addView(textView);


                    }
                }
            });

            // Setting Negative "NO" Button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.create();
            alertDialog.show();



        }


    });
```

**UPDATE**
This is what i added to the code inside the for loop but it shows only one output

```
    for (int n =0; n<pnarGotten; n++) {

                        textViewForPnar = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                        textViewForPnar.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        textViewForPnar.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        textViewForPnar.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        while (iterator.hasNext())
                        {
                            textViewForPnar.setText(iterator.next());

                        }
                        listLayout.addView(textViewForPnar);



                    }
```

Comment: simply replace your `for loop` with my answer code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Iterator` object of your inputList collection to retvieve elements from it:

```
    Iterator<String> iterator = inputList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    { 
        textView.setText(iterator.next());  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but when i use the Iterator it gives me only one value

Comment: Just call `iterator.next()` again that many times you need, assuming iterator has values : `terator.hasNext() == true`. That's why it's put in a while loop

Comment: Thanks for the help i just removed the while loop and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just simply replace your `for loop` with this code

```
for (int n = 0; n < pnarGotten; n++) 
{
    TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textView.setText(inputList.get(n));
    listLayout.addView(textView);
}
```